# .replace() only replaces one instance

Tags: replace, discord, bots

I'm trying to make a text that censors bad words if its in the input. Here's my code:

```
var NotAllowed  [
    'test'
]

var sendmessage = 'test this is a test to see if it censors this test'

for (i = 0; i < NotAllowed.length; i++){
     sendmessage = sendmessage.replace(NotAllowed[i], '######')
}

console.log(sendmessage)
```

The output looks something like "###### this is a test to see if it censors this test". I know about the "/g" thing but I don't know how to implement it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **RegExp** object it is used for matching text with a pattern.

```
var NotAllowed =[
    'test'
]

var sendmessage = 'test this is a test to see if it censors this test'

for (i = 0; i < NotAllowed.length; i++){
     sendmessage = sendmessage.replace(new RegExp(NotAllowed[i], "g"), '######')
}

console.log(sendmessage)
```